# Winforms: Best way to keep winforms app unlocked?

Tags: winforms

I have a winforms app, that's locking up during a web service request

I've tried using doEvents to keep the app unlocked, but its still not responsive enough,

How can I get around this locking, so that the app is responsive at all times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the web service request in a background thread. Be cautious of too many calls to Application.DoEvents().

Comment: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listView_mylist' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Comment: this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                listView_mylist.Items[pos].SubItems[5].Text = "success(no cert configured)";
            }));

Comment: Adding comments for the next guy - who needs the solution

Answer (score 5):

The best way is simply to do your IO work on another thread, perhaps via `BackgroundWorker`, or the async methods of `WebClient`.

See perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586184/trouble-with-webclient-downloaddataasync-not-downloading-the-data/1586232#1586232). Be sure to use `Invoke` when talking back to the UI controls (thread affinity); full example:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class MyForm : Form
{
    Button btn;
    TextBox txt;
    WebClient client;
    public MyForm()
    {
        btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Download";
        txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Multiline = true;
        txt.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        Controls.Add(btn);
        Controls.Add(txt);
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if (e.Cancelled) txt.Text = "Cancelled";
            else if (e.Error != null) txt.Text = e.Error.Message;
            else txt.Text = e.Result;
        });
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://google.com"));
    }
}
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }
}
```